# export "firebase/storage" and "firebase/firestore" in one file - Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I have a problem when I want to export both objects of my `firebase.js` file I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')
```

**firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ....
};
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase.app();
}
var storage = firebase.storage();
var firestore = firebase.firestore();

export default { storage, firestore };
```

**upload.js**

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  import { storage } from "../lib/firebase";

  function account() {
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
    const upload = () => {
      if (image == null) return;
      storage
        .ref(`/images/${image.name}`)
        ....
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Upload />
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default account;
```

If I export only the `storage` and import it in my `upload.js`file it works. What is the different?

Comment: Try removing `default` after export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you to try import per module. It should be something like this.

**firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ....
};
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase.app();
}
var storage = firebase.storage();
var firestore = firebase.firestore();

export { storage, firestore };
```

**upload.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
  import { storage, firestore } from "../lib/firebase";

  function account() {
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
    const upload = () => {
      if (image == null) return;
      storage
        .ref(`/images/${image.name}`)
        ....
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Upload />
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default account;
```

Hopefully can help you!

Comment: it was the "default" which I have to remove